# Borderlands 2 will only starts in a small window - Ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Tags: 14.04, graphics, 64-bit, games, lenovo

I was having trouble running Borderlands 2 on a newly imaged Ubuntu 14.04 64bit install.

- The machine is a Lenovo X1 Carbon.
- I had trouble with the libopenal1 error, but was able to fix it.
- I've ran all system updates and upgrades.
- I installed the Intel graphics driver using their Intel Graphics
  Update software, then rebooted.

Now when the game starts the screen is black except for a small box where the game intro shows and the main menu. But it's only a small window of the full image and I can't see everything. I can't use the arrow keys, alt+tab, or the mouse to get out of the game so I have to reboot the machine. The video in the box looks good, no discoloration or distortions. I am at a loss, does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue for Borderlands The Pre-Sequel with a Nvidia graphic card, same OS.

The problem actually occurs only in full screen mode, I set the game in window mode and it is fine now.

To avoid restarting your computer everytime, you can just connect to another virtual session (Ctrl + Alt + F1), kill the process and go back to the virtual session running your X server (Ctrl +Alt + F7 for me).

Answer (score 0):

You can also edit the graphics window sizes in the `willowgame` subdirectoriess, in the `.ini` files, search for `ResX` and `ResY` and set them to your actual screen size.